# I do not understand what Application.ProcessMessages in Delphi is doing

Tags: delphi

I'm a new to Delphi. My supervisor explained me that Application.ProcessMessages prevents freezing of the application and allocates some extra computing time. But in the docs of this command is always something explained about a queue system which is processed?
Please can somebody explain me the context?

Comment: That's nonsense. In no way it *"allocates some extra computing time"*. And it doesn't *"prevents freezing of the application"*; it forces the application to process all pending messages which in a long running code executed in the main (UI) thread *allows the UI look like it's alive*. But you should never execute a long running code in the main thread and so you should never need to use `Application.ProcessMessages`.

Comment: Write code which never calls `Application.ProcessMessages` and never needs to call it.

Comment: See this, http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessages

Comment: possible duplicate of [Delphi: How to prevent a single thread app from losing responses?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18879190/delphi-how-to-prevent-a-single-thread-app-from-losing-responses)

Comment: Recommended reading, [The Dark Side of Application.ProcessMessages](http://delphi.about.com/od/objectpascalide/a/delphi-processmessages-dark-side.htm).

Comment: You can't understand ProcessMessages until you have a deep understanding of Windows message queues. An SO question is not the way to gain that understanding. The question is thus too broad. I suggest you master the message queue first. I would also echo TLama's statement that your supervisor is ignorant of what ProcessMessages. You will learn nothing from this supervisor. Find a more qualified muse.

Comment: It might be poster's understanding of what the supervisor told. He could very well have said, regularly calling processmessages in some long processing job would prevent application to appear frozen, but would incur extra computing time.

Comment: I think you can understand ProcessMessages even when you have only a superficial understanding of message queues. In a real-life situation I could explain it in 2 minutes. On SO it might take a little longer (I'm not a fast typer). The advice to "master the message queue first" before trying to grasp what Application.ProcessMessages does feel to me like learning to build a car before getting your drivers license.

Comment: @Golez I think setting out with a superficial understanding of the message queue is what leads to the abuise and misuse of ProcessMessages.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

There is no short way to answer this question properly.

The primary means by which Windows applications interact with the operating system is via a messaging system.  Everything that happens in a windows application happens in response to a message.

**For example :**

If you click on the screen, the operating system decides which application got clicked and posts a message to that application indicating that it has received a click (along with the location of that click).

If a window is moved and reveals a part of your application beneath it, the operating system sends a message telling your application to repaint itself.

The list goes on.  Everything that happens is driven by messages.

Now, each application has one primary user-interface thread (the "Main" thread) and this thread has one primary function - it runs in an infinite loop that checks for these messages from the operating system and then executes the necessary code in response to those messages.

**The Problem**

You come along and start writing an application.  You might write some code like this :

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 99999999999 do begin
    SolveTheProblemsOfTheWorld(i);
    CalculatePiToABillionPlaces;
  end;
end;
```

In the larger structure of the program, execution in the main thread looks like this:

1. Check for messages
2. For each message - execute the associated handlers
3. Go back to Check for messages (loop)

So this loop is happily wizzing along when suddenly one of the associated handlers (`Button1Click` above) starts taking a very long time to complete.  *Key to understand is that one message handler must complete before the next one can run.*  If you click a scrollbar, for example, and drag it, but you've attached a handler to `OnClick` of the scrollbar that takes 10s to complete, then the drag operation will not be seen by your application until that click handler completes.  In the meantime, the message queue is filling up and the main thread is not doing anything about it.

Surely you've experienced this - suddenly your application does not respond to clicks.  You can't interact with it, you can't move the window, if you drag another window around overtop of it the application won't even repaint itself - it just fills up with whatever garbage you left on top of it.

**Enter ProcessMessages**

*The lazy, terrible solution to not putting your long-running code into a thread*

What you are doing when you are calling `Application.ProcessMessages` is, in the middle of one of these handlers, instructing the main thread to take a break to go back to check the message queue and empty any messages that have been piling up; to handle any clicks, window movements, inputs, keystrokes, to repaint itself if needed, etc.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var i : Integer;
begin
  for i := 0 to 99999999999 do begin
    SolveTheProblemsOfTheWorld(i);
    CalculatePiToABillionPlaces;
    Application.ProcessMessages;
  end;
end;
```

This may seem superficially like a sensible thing to do since it allows you to keep the application responsive during a long-running loop.  Ultimately, however, this style of programming is widely considered to be extremely poor practice for a large number of very good reasons. Suffice it to say that anywhere you are tempted to use `Application.ProcessMessages` is a solid case for moving that work to a background thread instead.

For more detail, let's have a look at the actual code :

```
procedure TApplication.ProcessMessages;
var
  Msg: TMsg;
begin
  while ProcessMessage(Msg) do {loop};
end;
```

So when you make this call to `Application.ProcessMessages` you are running a loop that is, one by one, emptying messages from the message queue (and executing all of the code that is attached to handlers that are reacting to those messages) until it is empty.  When it is empty and there are no more messages to process, control will return to the next line in your program.

The important point to take away is that the fluid, smooth interaction you experience when using a program is a complete illusion that depends exactly on this message loop being processed as quickly as possible.  The smaller the time delay between a message being posted to your application and the message being handled, the more your application will feel like it is alive and responsive.

It is for this reason that all code that is attached to user-interface handlers should be fast running.  Long running operations either need to be interrupted so that message handling can continue (ie: `Application.ProcessMessages`) or those operations need to be moved to a separate thread where they can execute without tying up the main thread and taking it away from its primary responsibility (which is to keep the user-interface alive).

---

For a really good article on the topic, see :

**[A Key's Odyssey](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447)** by Peter Below

([Internet Archive link](https://web.archive.org/web/20190117234226/http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447)... in case the above dies)

*Abstract: This article follows the path of a keystroke message through the VCL. You will learn how the key processing is implemented, how the OnKey events work and what intervention points for the programmer can be found in the whole process. In addition, things like message processing are explained, and you will learn how to trace messages in the debugger from the message loop to their eventual destination.*

Comment: It might be worth mentioning the reasons (eg re-entrancy) because the OP - and his supervisor! - need to know how bad it is. It's easy to think 'it's not best practice, but it will do', for example, whereas it really truly should not be done at all.

Comment: @DavidM I think I was sufficiently negative on the idea of using it.  The question is `What is ProcessMessages Doing?`, not `Why is it a bad idea?`.

Comment: @DavidM *"It's not best practice, but it will do"* is valid in lots of situations. If you are just learning Delphi, it is certainly one of them, and threading (especially GUI interaction from threads) is a complicated subject that many experiences programmers don't even fully grasp. And also when you have to quickly hack together a tool for whatever reason, it might help your out where a multi-threading implementation is overkill. I think J's answer (+1) is perfectly clear on the caveats of Application.ProcessMessages and saying not to use it at all is not reasonable.

Comment: @DavidM: Re-entrancy is always mentioned when the grave dangers of `Application.ProcessMessages` are narrated. It's also a total straw-man. Put your long running code in a thread and watch the same problems with re-entrancy happen if the UI has not disabled controls that initiate user actions which currently can not safely be initiated. Once that is fixed calls to `Application.ProcessMessages` usually are no longer problematic either. (Ignoring the possibility of stack overflows, which no answer so far mentions.)

Comment: @mghie Agreed.  I always bring this up when the re-entrancy bogeyman comes out.  Threads are even more prone to tricky bugs, in a lot of ways, than `ProcessMessages` is.  The real problem with `ProcessMessages` is that it encourages a coding style that makes for bad, tightly coupled, difficult to refactor, spaghetti/god applications that end up being a nightmare to maintain if they're allowed to get too big.

Comment: Or to put it another way: Somebody who isn't able to fix re-entrancy problems in the face of `Application.ProcessMessages` probably shouldn't be writing multithreaded code either, as the necessary reasoning about asynchronous execution is similar.

Comment: @J...: Yes, but then there are numerous ways of writing **bad, tightly coupled, difficult to refactor, spaghetti/god applications that end up being a nightmare to maintain** ;-)

Comment: +1 for `The lazy, terrible solution to not putting your long-running code into a thread`

Answer (score 35):

**Messaging**

A Delphi VCL application is a Windows application and a lot of communication between Windows components (like forms, edit boxes, but also hidden things like timers) is done using things called *messages*.

These messages are sent to a special queue. You can send such messages directly (using the `SendMessage` and `PostMessage` API functions), but messages are also sent indirectly when you set a property, like the `Text` of a `TEdit`.

These messages are used to notify controls that significant *events* have occurred within the program so they can respond appropriately. That concept of sending and responding to messages is the core principle of a paradigm known as event-driven programming.

Many modern operating systems are event-driven, such as Windows. In fact the Delphi VCL wraps a lot of Windows functionality, and many things you do will result in messages being sent between controls, which notify those controls of mouse clicks, keyboard presses, Windows-settings changing, application closing, control moving, etc.

**Mainthread doesn't process messages when executing code**

Operating systems also allow programs to have things called threads. Threads are like small pieces of a program that appear to operate simultaneously (and in some cases *actually do* run simultaneously). An application can have more than one thread, but there is always the main thread, which is also the thread responsible for accepting incoming messages and updating the GUI.

When the main thread of the application is idle (not executing code), it will check the queue to see if there are messages and process them. While other unrelated code is executing, this *cannot* happen. Consider this example:

```
Label1.Caption := 'A';
Sleep(5000); // Sleep is simulating a long, blocking process.
Label1.Caption := 'B';
```

If you execute this code, you would expect the label to get a caption of 'A', which changes to 'B' five seconds later. But this is not true. Setting the caption of a label triggers a repaint of the control through a message. Because the main thread is still blocked by this code (even by the Sleep command), the message isn't processed yet.

Only when the 5 seconds have passed and the caption is set to 'B', the main thread becomes idle and will execute the repaints that we triggered by setting the caption. Also note that other interaction, like clicking a button or dragging the window are postponed until the 5 seconds have passed. The entire UI freezes while the main thread is executing that code.

**Application.ProcessMessages to the rescue**

Application.ProcessMessages will just force the application to empty its message queue, so you can 'fix' the code like this:

```
Label1.Caption := 'A';
Application.ProcessMessages;
Sleep(5000);
Label1.Caption := 'B';
```

Usually there won't be just a Sleep in your code, but a lot of actual processing. By using `Application.ProcessMessage` frequently, you can keep the interface of the application responding, even when you are executing code.

But this is a bit dirty, the main thread (and the interface) will still be blocked, unless you manage to squeeze in a *lot* of calls to `Application.ProcessMessages`. And apart from processing paint messages, other messages are processed as well, so the application could process a click event right in the middle of your process.

So the docs you read are right: `Application.ProcessMessages` will empty the *message queue*. Your supervisor is not exactly right. It doesn't allocate extra processing time per say, but it just integrates the emptying of the message queue into the code that is executed, while normally the messages would remain in the queue until the application becomes idle.

**Internals**

Internally, the application itself does the same all the time. Its main procedure, `Application.Run`, looks like this (simplified pseudo code):

```
  repeat

    ProcessMessageFromTheQueue;
    If QueueIsEmpty then
      TellWindowsToWakeMeUpWhenANewMessageArrives;   

  until Terminated;
```

It's the processing that executes the code, for instance when a `WM_MOUSECLICK` message is processed, it will trigger (through some Delphi VCL magic), your `Button1Click` event handler. Since this is a single thread, everything runs sequentially, so you'll understand that `ProcessMessageFromTheQueue` only returns when the event handler is finished. Delphi handles only one message at a time, and only does the next when processing the previous one is finished.

Or does it?

`Application.ProcessMessages` looks like this:

```
  repeat

    ProcessMessageFromTheQueue;

  until QueueIsEmpty;
```

So it does almost the same as the application main loop: it picks a message from the queue and processes it. So this means, you can actually process the next messages while you are inside the processing of the last one. A convenient trick, but it can easily make your application messy and cause all kinds of unwanted side effects.

**The right way: Threads**

Most people consider it a better solution to use a separate thread for executing your code and just send signals to the main thread when it needs to update a label or a progress bar. That way, the main thread is idle all the time, and will keep responding to mouse clicks etc.

Threading is tough for a beginner, though. Some things to keep in mind:

- A thread (other than the main thread) should not directly update the GUI (for instance, a thread cannot set Label1.Caption. It *might* fail.
- Variables and other resources must not be changed by multiple threads at the same time, so you have to take precautions to prevent that (critical sections).
- You must (in most cases) prevent that a user executes the same action that is already executing.
- In many cases you must find a proper way to interrupt a running thread if a user wants to cancel the process or close the application.

Anyway, this answer shouldn't be a complete course about threading, but now at least you know what `Application.ProcessMessages` is for. 
Also note, it is considered 'evil' by many people, but as a beginner you can try it anyway to find out its strengths and weaknesses by yourself. If you do, I hope this information will at least inspire you to move to threads as soon as you are experienced enough for that next chapter.

Comment: calling `Sleep(5000)` in GUI thread is a nightmare for a Windows application. Updating a control is not a serious problem at all compared to else what can happen.

Comment: The Sleep is obviously just an example placeholder for a lot of actual processing.