# ProcessMessage method on c++ builder (bcb6)

Tags: c++, exception, c++builder, c++builder-6

What does `Application->ProcessMessages()` do on Borland C++Builder 6?

What is the meanning of this function?

When should I call it?

Is there any option that this function will throw an exception?

Comment: Here you have the answer of your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181713/i-do-not-understand-what-application-processmessages-in-delphi-is-doing

Comment: you should not call it directly (Windows will) but you can hook it up ... by changing the WinProc function handler to your own ... of coarse it is a good idea to call the original handler in it too so the VCL will work too.