# C#, multi-threading - Form not updating

Tags: c#, multithreading, forms

I have a monte-carlo simulation running across multiple threads with a progress bar to inform the user how it's going. The progress bar management is done in a separate thread using Invoke, but the Form is not updating.

Here is my code:

```
Thread reportingThread = new Thread(() => UpdateProgress(iSims, ref myBag));
reportingThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
reportingThread.Start();`
```

and here is the function being called:

```
private void UpdateProgress(int iSims, ref ConcurrentBag<simResult> myBag)
{
    int iCount;
    string sText;

    if (myBag == null)
        iCount = 0;
    else
        iCount = myBag.Count;

    while (iCount < iSims)
    {
        if (this.Msg.InvokeRequired)
        {
             sText = iCount.ToString() + " simultions of " + iSims + " completed.";
            this.Msg.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() { this.Msg.Text = sText; this.Refresh(); });
        }
       Thread.Sleep(1000);
       iCount = myBag.Count;
    }
}
```

I have used both Application.DoEvents() and this.refresh() to try to force the form to update, but nothing happens.

UPDATE: Here is the procedure calling the above function

```
private void ProcessLeases(Boolean bValuePremium)
    {
        int iSims, iNumMonths, iNumYears, iIndex, iNumCores, iSimRef;
        int iNumSimsPerThread, iThread, iAssets, iPriorityLevel;
        string sMsg;
        DateTime dtStart, dtEnd;
        TimeSpan span;
        var threads = new List<Thread>();
        ConcurrentBag<simResult> myBag = new ConcurrentBag<simResult>();
        ConcurrentBag<summaryResult> summBag = new ConcurrentBag<summaryResult>();

        this.Msg.Text = "Updating all settings";
        Application.DoEvents();
        ShowProgressPanel();

        iSims = objSettings.getSimulations();
        iNumCores = Environment.ProcessorCount;

        this.Msg.Text = "Initialising model";
        Application.DoEvents();
        iNumSimsPerThread = Convert.ToInt16(Math.Round(Convert.ToDouble(iSims) / Convert.ToDouble(iNumCores), 0));

        this.Msg.Text = "Spawning " + iNumCores.ToString() + " threads";

        for (iThread = 0; iThread < iNumCores; iThread++)
        {
            int iStart, iEnd;

            if (iThread == 0)
            {
                iStart = (iThread * iNumSimsPerThread) + 1;
                iEnd = ((iThread + 1) * iNumSimsPerThread);
            }
            else
            {
                if (iThread < (iNumCores - 1))
                {
                    iStart = (iThread * iNumSimsPerThread) + 1;
                    iEnd = ((iThread + 1) * iNumSimsPerThread);
                }
                else
                {
                    iStart = (iThread * iNumSimsPerThread) + 1;
                    iEnd = iSims;
                }
            }
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => ProcessParallelMonteCarloTasks(iStart, iEnd, iNumMonths, iSimRef, iSims, ref objDB, iIndex, ref objSettings, ref myBag, ref summBag));
            switch (iPriorityLevel)
            {
                case 1: thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Highest; break;
                case 2: thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal; break;
                default: thread.Priority = ThreadPriority.Normal; break;
            }
            thread.Start();
            threads.Add(thread);
        }

        // Now start the thread to aggregate the MC results
        Thread MCThread = new Thread(() => objPortfolio.MCAggregateThread(ref summBag, (iSims * iAssets), iNumMonths));
        MCThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
        MCThread.Start();
        threads.Add(MCThread);

        // Here we review the CollectionBag size to report progress to the user
        Thread reportingThread = new Thread(() => UpdateProgress(iSims, ref myBag));
        reportingThread.Priority = ThreadPriority.AboveNormal;
        reportingThread.Start();

        // Wait for all threads to complete
        //this.Msg.Text = iNumCores.ToString() + " Threads running.";
        foreach (var thread in threads)
            thread.Join();

        reportingThread.Abort();

        this.Msg.Text = "Aggregating results";
        Application.DoEvents();

        this.Msg.Text = "Preparing Results";
        Application.DoEvents();
        ShowResults();
        ShowResultsPanel();
    }
```

As you can see, there are a number of updates to the Form before my Invoked call and they all work fine - in each case, I am using Application.DoEvents() to update.

myBag is a ConcurrentBag into which each monte-carlo thread dumps it's results. By using the Count method, I can see how many simulations have completed and update the user.

Comment: would you mind to post a complete chunk of code to be tested?

Comment: @Leonardo - code added above.

Comment: Sorry to insist but still it can't be tested. What is "this.Msg" i.e.? is it a control?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
foreach (var thread in threads)
    thread.Join();
```

This is your problem.  You are blocking here so nothing will ever update in the UI thread until all your threads complete.

This is a critical point - `.DoEvents()` happens naturally and all by itself every time a block of code you have attached to a user interface event handler completes executing.  One of your primary responsibilities as a developer is to make sure that any code executing in a user interface event handler completes in a timely manner (a few hundred milliseconds,  maximum).  If you write your code this way then there is never, ever, a need to call `DoEvents()`... ever.

***You should always write your code this way.***

Aside from performance benefits, a major plus of using threads is that they are asynchronous by nature - to take advantage of this you have to write your code accordingly.  Breaking out of procedural habits is a hard one.  What you need to do is to forget the `.Join` altogether and get out of your `ProcessLeases` method here - let the UI have control again.

You are dealing with updates in your threads already so all you need is completion notification to let you pick up in a new handler when all of your threads finish their work.  You'll need to keep track of your threads - have them each notify on completion (ie: invoke some delegate back on the UI thread, etc) and in whatever method handles it you would do something like

```
 if (allThreadsAreFinished)  // <-- You'll need to implement something here
 {
      reportingThread.Abort();
      this.Msg.Text = "Preparing Results";         
      ShowResults();
      ShowResultsPanel();
 }
```

Alternatively, you could also simply call `ProcessLeases` in a background thread (making sure to correctly invoke all of your calls within it) and then it wouldn't matter that you are blocking that thread with a `.Join`.  You could also then do away with all of the messy calls to `.DoEvents()`.

Additionally, you don't need the call to `this.Refresh();` here :

```
 this.Msg.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker) delegate() { 
      this.Msg.Text = sText; 
      this.Refresh(); 
 });
```

If you *aren't* blocking the UI thread the control will update just fine without it and you'll only add extra work for nothing.  If you *are* blocking the UI thread then adding the `.Refresh()` call won't help because the UI thread won't be free to execute it any more than it will be free to execute the previous line.  This is programming chaotically - randomly adding code hoping that it will work instead of examining and understanding the reasons why it doesn't.

---

**Chapter 2 : The Workplace Analogy.**

Imagine the UI thread is like the manager.  The manager can delegate a task in several ways.  Using `.Join` as you've done it is a bit like the manager giving everyone a job to do - Joe gets one job, Lucy gets another, Bill gets a third, and Sara gets a fourth.  The manager has follow-up work to do once everyone is done so he comes up with a plan to get it done as soon as possible.

Immediately after giving everyone their task, the manager goes and sits at Joe's desk and stares at him, doing nothing, until Joe is done.  When Joe finishes, he moves to Lucy's desk to check if she is done.  If she isn't he waits there until Lucy finishes, then moves to Bill's desk and stares at him until he is done... then moves to Sara's desk.

Clearly this isn't productive.  Furthermore, each of the four team members have been sending email status updates (`Manager.BeginInvoke -> read your email!`) to their manager but he hasn't read any of them because he has been spending all of his time sitting at their desks, staring at them, waiting for them to finish their tasks.  He hasn't done anything else, for that matter, either.  The bosses have been asking what's going on, his phone's been ringing, nobody has updated the weekly financials - nothing.  The manager hasn't been able to do anything else because he decided that he needed to sit on his bottom and watch his team work until they finished.

> The manager isn't responding... The manager may respond again if you wait.  Do you want to fire the manager?
>
> <kbd>[YES - FIRE HIM]</kbd>   <kbd>[NO - Keep Waiting]</kbd>

Better, one would think, if the manager simply set everyone off to work on stuff and then got on with doing other things.  All he cares about is when they finish working so all it takes is one more instruction for them to notify him when their work is complete.  The UI thread is like your application's manager - its time is precious and you should use as little of it as absolutely necessary.  If you have work to do, delegate to a worker thread and don't have the manager sit around waiting for others to finish work - have them notify when things are ready and let the manager go back to work.

Comment: Is there any way I can continue to update the UI while those threads run?

Comment: @John Yes, your `reportingThread` is doing that already.  All you have to do is to *get out of the way*.  Your `.Join` call is blocking the UI thread and preventing it from doing its job.  Let your method exit right away after starting the threads and everything will unjam nicely.

Comment: @J - ok great thanks. I will define a way to measure when the threads have completed rather than use the Join method.

Comment: @John This really comes down to requiring a better understanding of how the UI thread works.  This is delphi, but you can replace `.DoEvents` with `ProcessMessages` and the story is the same : http://stackoverflow.com/a/25182276/327083  Take care to read the article : [A Key's Odyssey](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/38447).  `DoEvents()` is really a cheap hack, but for it to work your code has to actually execute it.  When you call `.Join` the execution stops there and nothing else happens until the `.Join` completes - you have to avoid that in the main thread at all costs.

Comment: @J - thank you for updating your answer with the example. I've never had to consider what the UI does while the real work is taking place and that's a very good example.

Answer (score 0):

Well the code is very partial, but at a glance if

```
this.Msg.InvokeRequired == false
```

the following code doesn't get executed. Can that be the issue?

Comment: I put an else clause into the code but it hasn't made a difference. When I was testing it in debugger mode, it did always step into the If condition, but didn't update the Form.

Comment: might you post a complete working chunk of code otherwise it's difficult to understand what happens thanks