# Are event handlers re-entrant in Embarcadero C++Builder?

Tags: c++, events, c++builder, reentrancy, c++builder-10.1-berlin

I'd like to ask some advice on how handle an Embarcadero CB10.1 issue with re-entrancy. Compiled in Debug configuration with "Disable all optimizations" set to true. I'm running on Win7.

I have a simple test case. A form with two buttons. The OnClick event handler for each button calls the same CPU intensive function. Below is the header file followed by the program file.

```
#ifndef Unit1H
#define Unit1H
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#include <System.Classes.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Controls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.StdCtrls.hpp>
#include <Vcl.Forms.hpp>
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
class TForm1 : public TForm
{
__published:    // IDE-managed Components
    TButton *Button1;
    TButton *Button2;
    void __fastcall Button1Click(TObject *Sender);
    void __fastcall Button2Click(TObject *Sender);
private:    // User declarations
    double __fastcall CPUIntensive(double ButonNo);
    double __fastcall Spin(double Limit);

public:     // User declarations
    __fastcall TForm1(TComponent* Owner);
};
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
extern PACKAGE TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endif



//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

#include <vcl.h>
#pragma hdrstop

#include "Unit1.h"
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
#pragma package(smart_init)
#pragma resource "*.dfm"
TForm1 *Form1;
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
__fastcall TForm1::TForm1(TComponent* Owner)
    : TForm(Owner)
{
}

//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button1Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Button1->Caption = "Pushed";
double retv = CPUIntensive(1);
Button1->Caption = "Button1";
if (retv) ShowMessage("Button1 Done");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

void __fastcall TForm1::Button2Click(TObject *Sender)
{
Button2->Caption = "Pushed";
double retv = CPUIntensive(2);
Button2->Caption = "Button2";
if (retv) ShowMessage("Button2 Done");
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

double __fastcall TForm1::CPUIntensive(double ButtonNo)
{
//
static bool InUse = false;
if (InUse) {
    ShowMessage("Reentered by button number " + String(ButtonNo));
    while (InUse) {};
    }
double retv;
InUse = true;
retv = Spin(30000);         // about 9 seconds on my computer
//retv += Spin(30000);      // uncomment if you have a faster computer
//retv += Spin(30000);
InUse = false;
return retv;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------

double __fastcall TForm1::Spin(double Limit)
{
double k;
for (double i = 0 ; i < Limit ; i++) {
    for (double j = 0 ; j < Limit ; j++) {
        k = i + j;
        // here there can be calls to other VCL functions
        Application->ProcessMessages(); // added so UI would be responsive (2nd case)
        }
    }
return k;
}
//---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

-
1st case : the code shown but WITHOUT the call to ProcessMessages().

When I run this and click on button 1, CPU usage jumps up to almost
100% for about 9 seconds. The form becomes unresponsive during this time.
Can't move the form or click on button 2.

That works as I would expect.

2nd case : To make the form responsive to the user during the CPU
intensive function, I added the ProcessMessages() call as shown.
Now, I can move the form around and click on other buttons.

That is not always good, because I could click on button 1 again or
even click on button 2. Either click would fire off the CPU intensive function again. To prevent the CPU intensive function from running the second time, I made a static boolean flag "InUse". I set that
when the function starts and clear it when the function completes.

So I check the flag when I enter the CPU intensive function and
if its set (it must have been set by a previous click on a button), I
show a message and then wait for the flag to clear.

But the flag never clears and my program loops on the 'while' statement
forever. I would like the program to just wait for the CPU intensive function
to complete and then just run it again.

If I set a breakpoint in the Spin() function after I hit the deadlock,
it never fires indicating that neither event is executing.

I know the VCL is not thread safe but here, all of the processing takes
place in the main thread. In my actual code, there are many calls to
VCL functions so the CPU intensive function has to remain in the main
thread.

I considered Critical Sections and Mutexes but since everything is in
the main thread, any use of them does no blocking.

Maybe its a stack issue? Is there a solution that lets me handle this without the deadlock?

Comment: This is a single-threaded program, so if you say `while (flag) { };` of course it will loop forever; none of the other code is running, so how could the value of `flag` change?  You *have* to return from the nested call so that the outer call can complete.

Comment: If you really want the operation to run as many times as the user clicks on the button, you'll have to have a counter.  But it might be more sensible to disable both buttons until the operation is complete.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I do not understand what Application.ProcessMessages in Delphi is doing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25181713/i-do-not-understand-what-application-processmessages-in-delphi-is-doing)

Comment: Seriously, the real problem here is that you do not understand how a message-based windows application works.  Once you take the time to understand what is going on, the rest of the questions answer themselves.

Answer (score 3):

> 2nd case : To make the form responsive to the user during the CPU intensive function, I added the ProcessMessages() call as shown. Now, I can move the form around and click on other buttons.

That is always the wrong solution.  The **correct** way to handle this situation is to move the CPU intensive code to a separate worker thread, and then have your button events start a new instance of that thread if it is not already running.  Or, keep the thread running in a loop that sleeps when it doesn't have work to do, and then have each button event signal the thread to wake up and do its work.  Either way, *NEVER* block the main UI thread!

> That is not always good, because I could click on button 1 again or even click on button 2. Either click would fire off the CPU intensive function again.
>
> To prevent the CPU intensive function from running the second time, I made a static boolean flag "InUse". I set that when the function starts and clear it when the function completes.

A better way would be to disable the buttons while the work is being performed, and re-enable them when finished. Then the work can't be re-entered to begin with.

But, even if you keep your flag, your function should just exit without doing anything if the flag is already set.

Either way, you should display a UI displayed telling the user when the work is in progress.  This becomes easier to manage if the work is done in a separate thread.

> So I check the flag when I enter the CPU intensive function and if its set (it must have been set by a previous click on a button), I show a message and then wait for the flag to clear.
>
> But the flag never clears and

That is because you are just running an endless loop that does nothing, so it doesn't allow the code to progress any further. And certainly not finish the existing work and reset the flag.

The *smallest* fix you can make to your existing code without re-writing it is to change `CPUIntensive()` to use `return 0` instead of `while (InUse) {}` when `InUse` is true.  That will allow a call to `ProcessMessages()` to exit and return control back to the previous `CPUIntensive()` call that is waiting to finish running.

> I know the VCL is not thread safe but here, all of the processing takes place in the main thread.

Thay is a BIG mistake.

> In my actual code, there are many calls to VCL functions so the CPU intensive function has to remain in the main thread.

That is not a good enough reason to perform the work in the main thread.  Move it to a worker thread, where it belongs, and have it sync with the main thread whenever it needs to access the UI.  Do as much work as possible in the worker thread, and sync only when absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

My question was not about threads but rather how to prevent multiple clicks of buttons from being acted upon while at the same time, not having the form become unresponsive. All of this in my single threaded VCL program. As I saw, when I did not have the call to ProcessMessages(), the form became unresponsive once a button was clicked (until the event handler completed its processing). When I added the call to ProcessMessages(), the form was TOO responsive in that mouse clicks caused event handlers to run **EVEN IF** the same mouse click's event handler was only part way complete when it called ProcessMessages(). The event handlers are not re-entrant but Windows/VCL was re-entering them when the second mouse button was pushed.

I needed a way to defer processing of mouse button events while at the same time processing messages so the form did not appear unresponsive.

ProcessMessages() was not going to work here. It dispatched every message that it found in the message queue.

I found a way to go part way, a version of ProcessMessages that checked the message queue and if a non-mouse button message was there, dispatch it. Otherwise, leave the messsage in the queue for later.

Here is the code I ended up with to replace the call to ProcessMessages:

```
// set dwDelay to handle the case where no messages show up
MSG msg;
DWORD dwWait = MsgWaitForMultipleObjects(0, NULL, FALSE, dwDelay, QS_ALLINPUT);
if (dwWait == WAIT_TIMEOUT) {   // Timed out?
    // put code here to handle Timeout
    return;
    }
// Pump the message queue for all messages except Mouse button messages
// from 513 to 521  (0x0201 to 0x0209)
bool MsgAvailable;
while (true) {
    MsgAvailable = PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, 0, 0, PM_NOREMOVE);
    if (!MsgAvailable) break;   // no messages available
    if (msg.message <= WM_MOUSEMOVE) {
        // Message from WM_NULL to and including WM_MOUSEMOVE
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_NULL, WM_MOUSEMOVE);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        continue;
        }
    if (msg.message >= (WM_MOUSELAST+1)) {
        // Message from WM_MOUSELAST+1 to the last message possible
        GetMessage(&msg, NULL, WM_MOUSELAST+1, 0xFFFFFFFF);
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
        continue;
        }
    // if all that's left is mouse button messages, get out
    if (msg.message > WM_MOUSEMOVE || msg.message < WM_MOUSELAST+1) break;
    }
return;
```

Now the event handler gets to finish its processing without re-entry. All of the non-mouse button events get processed. When the event handler is done, control goes back to the main VCL thread message pump and the waiting mouse button event(s) is/are fired.