# Loading form as overlay while function runs in background

Tags: delphi, vcl, jvcl

When i call a function and it "runs" (Can be take up to 3 seconds - refresh function getting data from api server) I would like to show a loadingform  as an Ajax Loading Indicator  as an overlay above the main form.

My previous attempts have all failed. I had tried to change the Create the LoadingForm that it is directly shown after the Main created. Then I tried LoadingForm.Show/Showmodal. In the modal sequence stops and only continues when I close the form and show the window does not close despite .

I also had the situation that the form was opened but the gif wasnt showing, the place where it should be was just white and stayed white - no image no animation

[image]

Any idear?

Comment: Is your function running in a separate thread?

Comment: No its in the main unit.

Comment: Well, that means that the GUI is not responsive during the function call.

Comment: Well i have atm the MainForm (Where the function is which takes some seconds) and a seperate form. So each time i call the "refresh" function i want to display overlay form could you post an code example?

Comment: Provided that your function is able to run in a separate thread, see [Delphi: How to prevent a single thread app from losing responses?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18880023/576719).

Comment: The function needs access to a grid of the main form ...

Comment: Put the data into a container, and use a virtual grid.

Comment: @Hidden What you need to grasp is that a thread cannot be simultaneously busy performing work, and running a GUI. You will need two threads. This will require a redesign of your program.

Comment: If your blocking method is a loop you have three options.  1) Show the dialog and explicitly call its refresh/repaint methods periodically during the loop.  2) call `ProcessMessages` periodically during the loop. 3) Move the work to a background thread and use callbacks.  Method 3 is the ideal, generally.  If your blocking call does not contain a loop (or is not under your control) you really have only one option - #3, use a thread.

Comment: did you try a background worker component or async call like suggested in the answers here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21430812/background-worker-delphi ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The code below uses a thread to mimic a long time running block in its `Execute` method and the `OnProgress` "callback" to notify the form the percent done has changed.

It's a very minimal example but it can show you one of the right directions in my opinion.
Notice that no error checking nor exception handling are currently performed.

---

**`Unit1.pas`** *the main form and the thread class*

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.StdCtrls, Unit2;

type
  TMyRun = class(TThread)
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
    public
      OnProgress: TProgressEvent;
  end;

  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
    procedure FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private declarations }
    FProgressForm: TfrmProgress;
    procedure myRunProgress(Sender: TObject; Stage: TProgressStage;
        PercentDone: Byte; RedrawNow: Boolean; const R: TRect; const Msg: string);
    procedure myRunTerminate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

procedure TMyRun.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
  r: TRect;
begin
  for i := 1 to 100 do begin
    if Terminated then
      Break;

    Sleep(50);//simulates some kind of operation

    if Assigned(OnProgress) then
      Synchronize(procedure
          begin
            OnProgress(Self, psRunning, i, False, r, '');
          end);
  end;
end;

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FProgressForm := TfrmProgress.Create(nil);
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FProgressForm.Free;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  with TMyRun.Create do begin
    FreeOnTerminate := True;
    OnProgress := myRunProgress;
    OnTerminate := myRunTerminate;
  end;
  FProgressForm.ShowModal;
end;

procedure TForm1.myRunProgress(Sender: TObject; Stage: TProgressStage;
  PercentDone: Byte; RedrawNow: Boolean; const R: TRect; const Msg: string);
begin
  FProgressForm.ProgressBar1.Position := PercentDone;
end;

procedure TForm1.myRunTerminate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FProgressForm.Close;
end;

end.
```

**`Unit1.dfm`**

```
object Form1: TForm1
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  Caption = 'Form1'
  ClientHeight = 81
  ClientWidth = 181
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  Position = poDesktopCenter
  OnCreate = FormCreate
  OnDestroy = FormDestroy
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object Button1: TButton
    Left = 48
    Top = 24
    Width = 91
    Height = 25
    Caption = 'Run the thread'
    TabOrder = 0
    OnClick = Button1Click
  end
end
```

**`Unit2.pas`** *the progress dialog*

```
unit Unit2;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes,
  Vcl.Graphics, Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.ComCtrls;

type
  TfrmProgress = class(TForm)
    ProgressBar1: TProgressBar;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  frmProgress: TfrmProgress;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

**`Unit2.dfm`**

```
object frmProgress: TfrmProgress
  Left = 0
  Top = 0
  BorderStyle = bsSizeToolWin
  Caption = 'frmProgress'
  ClientHeight = 51
  ClientWidth = 294
  Color = clBtnFace
  Font.Charset = DEFAULT_CHARSET
  Font.Color = clWindowText
  Font.Height = -11
  Font.Name = 'Tahoma'
  Font.Style = []
  OldCreateOrder = False
  PixelsPerInch = 96
  TextHeight = 13
  object ProgressBar1: TProgressBar
    Left = 16
    Top = 16
    Width = 265
    Height = 17
    TabOrder = 0
  end
end
```

---

Referring to the comment which states that the long time running operations need to access a grid in the main form, in order to avoid to block the VCL thread on that object:

1. To avoid the access to the VCL data from the thread - *it's the preferred way if the already modified data have to be reused in the routine*:

   - pass a copy of the grid's data to the thread - say in the constructor
   - update the copy
   - update the grid with the edited copy of the data after the thread has finished - i.e. after the `ShowModal` returns.
2. To access the form's object from the thread - *this can be done if the form's objects are accessed for very short time intervals*:

   - use a [synchronized block](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) to get the data from the grid
   - update the grid in a thread's syncronized callback - i.e. in the `myRunProgress` or in the `myRunTerminate` method

For different use cases a *mixed approach* could also make sense (pass the copy in the constructor/update the grid in a thread's syncronized block) if your routine doesn't take in account the already changed data: choose the method which best suits your needs.

If another external thread updates the grid, a `thread1` could read the data then fill a form's private queue - say a `TThreadList` or another collection in a `TCriticalSection` block - and notify a `thread2` to perform a job on the queue but I hope this is probably not needed to have your job done.

Comment: From comments, the OP said that the background task needs to access a vcl data grid. That is difficult to do, unless you refactor the task to access data from a structure independent of the vcl.

Comment: @LURD I can't understand your point fully: the data in the grid could be accessed in a synchronized block trying to avoid a long time locking of the VCL thread. Or the grid's data can be passed in the thread constructor. The datagrid can be update safely in the `myRunProgress` procedure. By the code the OP has given, I can't guess anything more

Comment: We are all guessing here, since we can't tell if it is practical to access grid data in a synchronized block or pass it through the constructor, and later update the data in a synchronized callback. Anyway you don't mention any of this in your answer. The right thing to do is to refactor the code, avoiding dependency of the GUI.

Comment: @LURD if the job relies heavily on the grid, 2 threads can be used: one reads, fills a queue, the other reads the queue and performs the UI update. But per the question itself, do you think I should extend my answer with that?

Comment: The OP is asking for code, but the question incomplete and shows no research effort. Just pointing out the shortcomings in the question and expand on ways to handle (or avoid!) access of vcl data from a thread would be ok.

Comment: I don't think the question can be answered at all. The addition of a bounty doesn't make it any more clear.

Answer (score 0):

Create the dialog form setting:

```
BorderIcons = []
BorderStyle = bsDialog
FormStyle = fsStayOnTop
Position = poScreenCenter
```

in the main form when you call your function write:

```
procedure TFormMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
    Enabled:=false;
    try
        FormDialog.Show;
        FormDialog.Refresh;

        MyLongRunProcedure; // calls your procedure here

    finally        
        Enabled:=true;
        FormDialog.Close;
    end;
end;
```

It should work..

Comment: if you want/need you can access FormDialog from within your function to update a progress bar or update a status label..